# Custom Sessions and not hitting Application::newSession

Tags: java, session, wicket

I'm using Apache Wicket 6.10 and I'm having casting exception issues with Apache Wicket.

My custom session object extends the WebSession class and I am returning a new instance of SCSSession in WicketApplication (Extends WebApplication)::newSession.

The exception is:

```
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession cannot be cast to SCSSession
at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1279)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1358)
```

What I have found in my debugging is that new Sessions are being created from org.apache.wicket.Application class.

At the moment, I'm a little dumb founded, why is WicketApplication (extended by WebAplication also extended by Application) using the Application::newSession rather than my WicketApplication?

The call for the session is coming from an embedded panel. Does this have anything to do with the issues in session initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefaultPageFactory#createPage() is from Wicket 1.4.x. You should check your classpath.

Comment: Winner. I was about to write my solution. Here is what I found. http://theexceptioncatcher.com/blog/2013/09/debuggingdepedency-issue-with-maven/

WicketStuff changed the way they label stuff.